# Is casting "this" from a parent class method to a child a good practice?

Tags: c++, casting, this

I'm implementing a very basic base class for running a Finite State Machine. Here is what I did ...

```
/**
 * @class FSM
 * @brief This class is a base class for an object that wants to run a Finite State Machine.
 * That object, let's say States, would need to inherit from FSM<States>,
 * and its methods would then be available as state actions of the state machine.
 */
template<typename States>
class FSM
{
    public :
        /**
         * @typedef StateAction is an alias for a pointer to a method of States, only callable that can be a state of the FSM
         */
        typedef void(States::*StateAction)(void);

        /**
         * @fn FSM(States* states, StateAction initial_state_action = nullptr)
         * @brief Constructs a FSM object whose actions are of type StateAction
         */
        FSM(States* states, StateAction initial_state_action = nullptr)
        :
            m_states(states),
            m_state_action(initial_state_action),
            m_is_entering_state(true)
        {}

        /**
         * @fn bool update()
         * @brief Performs an iteration of the FSM
         * @returns true if and only if the FSM has a state to run
         */
        bool update()
        {
            if(m_states && m_state_action)
            {
                auto previous_action = m_state_action;
                (m_states->*m_state_action)();
                m_is_entering_state = (m_state_action != previous_action);
            }
            return m_state_action != nullptr;
        }

    protected :
        /**
         * @fn void setState(StateAction state_action)
         * @brief Change the state of the FSM
         * @param[in] state_action Method of States that implements the new state behavior (nullptr stops the FSM)
         */
        void setState(StateAction state_action)
        {
            m_state_action = state_action;
        }

        /**
         * @fn bool isEnteringState() const
         * @brief Tells whether the current state has just be entered or is looping, waiting for a transition
         * @returns] true if and only if the current state hasn't yet been executed since it has been changed
         */
        bool isEnteringState() const
        {
            return m_is_entering_state;
        }

    private :
        States*     m_states;            //!< Pointer to the child class that implements the States of the FSM
        StateAction m_state_action;      //!< Pointer to the method of States that implements the current state behavior
        bool        m_is_entering_state; //!< Tells whether the current state has just be entered or is looping, waiting for a transition
};
```

... and how it's intended to be used :

```
class States : public FSM<States>
{
    public :
        States()
        :
            FSM<States>(this, &States::state1)
        {}

        void state1()
        {
            // Actions to perform when entering the state
            if(isEnteringState())    cout << "Entering ";

            // Actions to perform constantly (regulate a system, detect events, etc...)
            cout << __func__ << endl;

            // Transitions to other states
            bool is_event_detected = true;
            if(is_event_detected)    setState(&States::state2);
        }

        void state2()
        {
            if(isEnteringState())    cout << "Entering ";

            cout << __func__ << endl;

            bool is_exit_detected = true;
            if(is_exit_detected)    setState(nullptr);
        }
};

int main()
{
    States fsm;
    bool is_fsm_running = true;
    while(is_fsm_running)
    {
        is_fsm_running = fsm.update();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The only purpose of storing m_states in FSM (pointer to the derived object that implements the states) is to call m_state_action in update(), which is a pointer to a method of the derived object. Instead, I wonder whether casting *this* (which is of type FSM*) to States* with a static_cast is a good practice ?

```
(static_cast<States*>(this)->*m_state_action)();
```

Is the behavior well defined ? (I know it works with mingw 7.30)

Also, as a side question, templating FSM with a class that is its child looks a bit weird (class States : public FSM)... Could I do this differently ?

Comment: Is `States` *always* going to be inheriting from `FSM<States>`? Then why not simply make the `state_action` a `virtual` function that is overridden by the `States` class? Or why not use `std::function` instead of an explicit member-function pointer? Then the `States` class can use any callable object it wants.

Comment: To the side question: this is a known pattern, the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP).

Comment: Yes States is always intended to inherit from FSM. I don't want to override it in States, since FSM is an interface that just brings functionalities. If I'm not wrong, a std::function cannot simply store a class method (binding with the object as first parameter works, but it's verbose and very convenient...)

Comment: @AntoineMorel: You can use a lambda for that; it's not too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's legal under two conditions:

1. `States` must inherit publicly and non-virtually from `FSM<States>`.

   Your design already calls for this usage pattern, but it would be best to add a `static_assert` to enforce this requirement.
2. The object is actually an instance of `States`.

   It is difficult if not impossible to prevent `struct BogusStates : FSM<TrueStates> {};`

   You can at least prevent anyone from directly instantiating `FSM<States>` by giving it a `protected` constructor.

Comment: So (static_cast<States*>(this)->*m_state_action)(); is legal ; could it be called a "downcast" ? At compilation, static_cast wouldn't fail is there is no known conversion from FSM<States> to States ?

Comment: @AntoineMorel: Your parentheses aren't placed correctly but I get the idea.  Yes, it is a downcast.  There is a conversion at stage 2 of template instantiation, when the template parameters are known.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is, is it safe *enough*?

The possible abuse is fairly trivial:

```
class FooStates { }

class BarStates : FSM <FooStates> { }
```

Now a cast of `this` in `FSM <FooStates>` will cast a `BarStates*` to a `FooStates*`. A possible protection is to use a `dynamic_cast`, but that requires `FSM<>` to have a virtual method. It's a runtime check, but you only need to do it once. Unfortunately, you can't do it in the `FSM` constructor because at that point the derived object `States` has not yet been created.

Comment: Do you think it might be possible to have `friend class States; /* the template argument */` along with private special member functions, to prevent the abuse in your answer (same as in my bullet point #2)?  ISTR that combining `friend` with templates is restricted.

Comment: Yes, as suggested in [this article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/12/curiously-recurring-template-pattern/) I found on FluentC++. I successfully tested it

Answer (score 0):

Templates in C++ used the idea of the duck typing. So it's safe to call any function of `State` type without any casts. It just will not compile if this method doesn't exist.

There is the code example to illustrate what I mean: https://rextester.com/MPXX23993

Comment: This misses the name lookup problem. When compiling `FSM` in the first pass (no template argument yet), the name lookup for `this->*m_state_action` fails. The method exists, but only in a base class, but that base class is a template argument and therefore only available in the second pass.

Comment: @MSalters: It's a **pointer**.  A pointer doesn't do name lookup on the thing it is pointing to (which is dynamically changing, anyway).  The compiler is checking the types, though.  You'd have a problem for name lookup in the derived class, but in the OP's code the only usages of the name `m_state_action` are in the base class that definitely contains that member.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Fair point, I got sidetracked by the "make it `virtual`" comment.